# Calling an Inline Function on a webform inside of mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am trying to call a function inside of a ListView control Item Template.  The function is adding a new row on the event of a group change.
        `<ItemTemplate>
        <%# AddGroupingRowIfParentHasChanged() %>
        <tr style="">
           <td><asp:Label ID="ClauseLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Clause") %>' /></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="ClauseNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClauseName") %>' /></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="SortOrderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SortOrder") %>' /></td>
<td><asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteClause" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" CommandName="DeleteClause"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>`

I am using a webform that resides inside of an MVC application.
The page used to be apart of a webform application, but I am looking to move it into a new MVC application.  Due to the overall complexity of the form, I want to avoid redeveloping it as mvc.

The issue is that I am unable to call `AddGroupingRowIfParentHasChanged()`

the Error that I am getting on this line is, The name 'AddGroupingRowIfParentHasChanged()' does not exist in the current context.

I cannot seem to find any resolution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with Visual Studio, when I was copying over code.  I commented those lines out, built the solution then re-added those lines and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@foreach` for your data source, replace server control by razor syntax like this.

MVC view engine did not support `<% %>` in razor with version later than 1.0

```
@foreach(var item in datasource){
<tr style="">
           <td><label>@item.Clause</label></td>
<td><label>@item.ClauseName</label></td>
<td><label>@item.SortOrder</label></td>
<td><button Id="btnDeleteClause" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: I understand I would be able to rewrite the page using razor syntax, however, I am looking to keep this page as a webform.